# The effect of nitric acid on the rate of corrosion of copper

Tags: corrosion

I conducted an experiment concerning the rate of corrosion of copper when submerged in three solutions. In the first solution, 5ml concentrated nitric acid and 10 ml distilled water was added. In the second solution, 5ml concentrated nitric acid, 7.5 ml distilled water and 2.5 ml 5 molar NaCl solution was added. In the last solution, 5 ml nitric acid, 5 ml distilled water and 5 ml NaCl solution was added. I expected the rate of corrosion to be the fastest when submerged into a solution where more NaCl solution is evident, but this was not the case. My results were quite the opposite. The rate of corrosion was the fastest in the '5ml concentrated nitric acid and 10 ml distilled water' solution, which confused me. I repeated the experiment multiple times, but the results came out the same.(I used colorimetry to determine the rate of corrosion)

I proceeded to take the temperature of the three solutions and that's when I discovered that temperature played a huge role in the rate of corrosion. The solution with an addition of only distilled water had the highest initial temperature, while the solution with the addition of only the NaCl solution had the lowest initial temperature.

However, I don't quite understand why my results are the way they are. Isn't salt supposed to accelerate the rate of corrosion?

(the color of the distilled water solution after corrosion was blue, while the color of the NaCl solution was green).

Comment: What was your reasoning into thinking salt would speed up the corrosion? HNO3 is the one attacking the copper. When you add salt, what I believe is happening is that part of the nitric acid is reacting with NaCl, thus not all of it attacks the copper

Comment: How did you discover that temperature played a huge role in the rate of oxidation? Did you measure the rate of oxidation while keeping the solution composition constant and varying the temperature?Did you then perform the original experiment again, being careful to keep all solutions at the same temperature?

Comment: Another contributing factor may be that increasing the ionic strength decreases activity of ions.

Comment: Please correct the title because no distilled water is at play.